# Dynamic table rows overflow inside the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, html-table, overflow

I create a dynamic table using jQuery and getting data from .asp file using JSON.

I can get all the data, but when filling the table with data, there is no scrollbar and the rows are overflowed, so I can't see and click them.

Can somebody help me please with this task?

Here is the table in HTML:

```
<table id="errorCodesBodyfh">
    <tbody id="tabBodyfh">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here is how I fill it:

```
for (i = json.errorlistcount - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    data = json.errorlist[i];
    var errsplit = data.split(";");
    var row = [];
    var errorTime = timeFormat.get(errsplit[0]);
    var errorCode = parseInt(errsplit[1]);
    var errorDetails = errsplit[2];

    if (errorCode < 3000) {
        img = imgWarning;
        var imgType = typWarning;
    } else {
        img = imgError;
        imgType = typError;
    }

    row[i] = '<tr id="row' + i +'">'
    + '<td style="width: 10%;"><img '+ img + '></td>'
    + '<td>'+ imgType + ' ' + errorCode + '<br>Time ' + errorTime + '</td>'
    + '<td style="display: none;">' + errorDetails + '</td></tr>';
    $('#tabBodyfh').append(row[i]);
}
```

Comment: `var row = '';`

`row =  '<tr id="row' + i +'">'.....` and `$('#tabBody' + newUnit).append(row);` instead of `row[i]`; ?

Comment: vivek_23, tried it before, there is no difference in the behavior.

Comment: If you are able to fill the rows in the table properly an d just not able to see them, then it's more of a CSS problem than jquery. Is there any explicit height set the table or any of its parent? Also, do check if rows are actually getting created properly using `inspect element` in the browser.

Comment: @vivek_23, in CSS I have the height of the table. Here is the link of the screenshot [link] (https://imgur.com/a/kKJzhIz)

Comment: Try removing `overflow-y:hidden` and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't append each time in table.Instead of this build markup once and append like below code using `+=`.Each time go to dom and append gives performance problem.

```
var html = '';
for (i = json.errorlistcount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  html += '<tr id="row' + i + '">' +
    '<td style="width: 10%;"><img ' + img + '></td>' +
    '<td>' + imgType + ' ' + errorCode + '<br>Time ' + errorTime +
    '</td>' +
    '<td style="display: none;">' + errorDetails + '</td></tr>';

}
$('#tabBodyfh').append(html);
```

Wrap your table with some div and try with css like this.Or you can apply css direct in your table.

```
<div class="yourtable_container">
<table> </table>
</div>


.yourtable_container{ overflow:auto; width: 500px;height: 200px; }
```

Comment: Shree, still no scroll bar but fixed few elements inside the table.